# Is it possible to enumerate NSDictionary keys to set datamodel member values?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a dictionary contains (for example)

```
"Mark":"Name","Green":"Lastname"
```

and I have a datamodel with following:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Lastname;
```

Can I enumerate dictionary allkeys to set datamodel member values?

something like this:

```
let newPerson = CoreDataHelper.insertManagedObject(NSStringFromClass(Person), managedObjectContext: self.moc) as! Person

for key in self.newPersonDict!.allKeys {
    newPerson.key = self.newPersonDict!.objectForKey(key)
}
```

Thanks,
Max

Comment: You can do this with reflection, but I'd recommend against it. Instead, you should create an `initWithAttributes:` initializer for `Person` that explicitly assigns each property.

Comment: A few side notes: 1) Your dictionary is mixed up; you probably want `Name` and `LastName` as the keys, not the values. 2) The convention for property names is camelCase, not UpperCase. 3) `Name` and `Lastname` don't really make sense together; you should probably have `GivenName` and `FamilyName` or just `Name` by itself, depending on your use case.

Comment: try `newPerson.setValue(self.newPersonDict!.valueForKey(key), forKeyPath: key)`

Comment: @Nishant: Thanks it works. If you answer the question I will accept and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @masgar: Thanks. I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let newPerson = CoreDataHelper.insertManagedObject(NSStringFromClass(Person), managedObjectContext: self.moc) as! Person

for key in self.newPersonDict!.allKeys {
    newPerson.setValue(self.newPersonDict!.valueForKey(key), forKeyPath: key)   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use func setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(_ keyedValues: [NSObject : AnyObject])

Answer (score 0):

As said in one of the comments, you can achieve this with reflection. There are probably better ways to do this, but here is an example on how you can do it

```
class YourClass : NSObject {

    func getKeys() -> Array<String> {
        let mirror = reflect(self)
        var keys = [String]()
        for i in 0..<mirror.count {
            let (name,type) = mirror[i]
            keys.append(name)
        }
        return keys
    }

    func getObjectForKey(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return self.valueForKey(key)
    }

}
```

You would still have to cast AnyObject? to your specific type, and be careful, valueForKey can result in exceptions when it's called with an unknown key.